# I need the right way to place the template files in micro service

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, microservices

I am developing an ecommerce site. For template I am using thymleaf template engine. The problem scenario is, I have two template for view. One is for admin user and another is for customer. Should I place all the admin and customer template  in gateway microservice? or I have to create two microservice,one is for rendering customer template another is for admin template rendering over gateway service. Will I face any security difficulty if I create two microservice over gateway servcice for view rendering? Or, will I place all admin and customer template in gateway service?Please help me to fix it.

Is the picture design  is okay to do? or  I have to go for gateway solution. 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt50Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to my own experience, it is best to have two separate microservices and gateway for user and admin panel.

Some of important characteristics of a microservice :

- Application logic is broken down into small-grained components with
  welldefined boundaries of responsibility that coordinate to deliver a
  solution.
- Each component has a small domain of responsibility and is deployed
  completely independently of one another. Microservices should have
  responsibility for a single part of a business domain.

So separate the microservices as far as possible according to their concerns.

If you are just getting started with microservices I would suggest checking out this [link](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html).